# iPython Notebook quits displaying bar chart

Tags: matplotlib, graph, jupyter-notebook

I have a Python script that I wanted to use to learn iPython Notebook on and I'm having an issue with it displaying the graphs as it proceeds through the text.

Here's a partial of the code I'm working with.

```
#import baseline and iteration files
df_final = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(CSV_dir, 'mean_prop_iter.csv'))
baseline = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(CSV_dir, 'mean_prop_base.csv'))

## create base figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

## create histogram
df_final['iter_prop_in'].hist(bins=[0.5, 0.51, 0.52, 0.53, 0.54,
                                    0.55, 0.56, 0.57, 0.58, 0.59, 0.60],
                              rwidth=1.0, align='mid', facecolor='red')
```

At this point everything looks fine.
[image: the histogram is properly displayed]

My subsequent commands aren't what I expect.

```
## define x-axis limits
label_range = np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1)
labels      = ax1.set_xticks(label_range)

## turn off ticks along the top and right axes
plt.tick_params(axis='both', top='off', right='off', direction='out')
```

Here is where the new x-axis limits are properly displayed but the histogram is not displayed. The y-axis tick limits also become 0 to 1, which I don't expect.
[image]

If I run the same commands in Python 2.7 (Anaconda Spyder), the histogram displays as I expect.
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you're doing it in the Notebook in separate cells. You should group your plotting commands pertaining to the same figure into a single cell.

As your code currently stands, the Notebook thinks you're referring to a new figure.

---

Unrelated tip: you might consider suffixing your plot-related commands with a `;`, which indicates returned-value output suppression. Omitting this tends to print lots of gibberish in the cell output.

Comment: That unrelated tip was very helpful for me! Been wondering if I could get rid of the gibberish for months now, but it didn't bother me enough to ask. Here's another unrelated tip: generate the bins with `import numpy as np; bins=np.linspace(0,1,11)` instead of a list (it creates an equally spaced interval between 0 and 1 that has 11 values, inclusive of 0 and 1).